# Create definition without title

Tags: amsmath, theorems

I would like to know how I make this kind of quote in my text. I know it's not theorem or definition. Thanks for the help

[image]

Comment: A `quote` or `blockquote` might do.

Comment: I want to create this definition (6) and then reference it in the document

Comment: @user50098 - Is the "thing" really an equation? If so, just give it an equation number and call it "equation" in any cross-references.

Comment: The block in the picture looks like a `multline` environment to me. This requires dealing with the line breaks manually though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a `multline` environment where the first/last equations are offset left/right and those in the middle are centred:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{multline}
  p(\tau, j \,\vert\, \bm{x},t)\, \mathrm{d}\tau
    \equiv \text{the probability, given $\bm{X}(t) = \bm{x}$, that the \textit{next}} \\
    \text{reaction in the system will occur in the infinitesimal time} \\
      \text{interal $[t + \tau, t + \tau + \mathrm{d}\tau)$, \textit{and} will be an $R_j$ reaction.}
  \label{eq:this_thing}
\end{multline}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

You can use `\eqref{eq:this_thing}` to reference the equation within your document.

Comment: That's surely the way the text in the image was written. This doesn't make the formatting appealing, though. Just to be picky: the documentation of the `amsbsy` (sub)package states that `bm` is to be preferred. And the image uses `\mathbf`, by the way.

Comment: @egreg: I agree. The line spacing in such a textual context should match the surrounding paragraph text at least. I'll update for [`bm`](//ctan.org/pkg/bm).

Comment: just in case such a construct is embedded in an italic environment, like a theorem, shouldn't `\textit` instead be `\emph`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes, for proper, visible, `emph`asis.

Answer (score 2):

A proposal

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{5}
\begin{align}
 \MoveEqLeft[5] \fcolorbox{white}{yellow}{\phantom{X}}~~p(\tau,j|\mathbf{x},t)\equiv\text{the probability, given
 $\boldsymbol{X}(t)=\textbf{x}$, that the \emph{next}} \notag\\
 & \text{reaction in the system will occur in the infinitesimal}\notag\\
 &\quad \text{interval $[t+\tau,t+\tau+\mathrm{d}\tau)$, and will be an $R_j$
 reaction}\;.\label{eq:Defp}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A screen shot would help ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer done

Answer (score 0):

If you want such formatting (I don't like it), at least make the text into a regular paragraph, as those unequal lines are very distracting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\newenvironment{eqdef}[1][0.8]
 {\begin{equation}\begin{minipage}[b]{#1\columnwidth}}
 {\end{minipage}\end{equation}}

\begin{document}

See~\eqref{foo} for the definition.

\lipsum*[3]
\begin{eqdef}\label{foo}
$p(\tau, j \mid \mathbf{x},t)\,d\tau\equiv{}$the probability, 
given $\mathbf{X}(t) = \mathbf{x}$, that the \emph{next}
reaction in the system will occur in the infinitesimal time
interval $[t + \tau, t + \tau + d\tau)$, \emph{and} will be 
an $R_j$ reaction.
\end{eqdef}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

With the optional argument you can modify the size of the inner minipage.

[image]